# RelativeSource binding not resolving

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, relativesource

I have a ContextMenu in a TreeView

```
UserControl (DataContext=ViewModel)
    |
    |
    ---- TreeView (ItemSource=MyItems)
           |
           |
           ----- Items (ItemSource=MyChildrenItems)
                   |
                   |
                   ----- ContextMenu
```

I want to bind the Command of the ContextMenuItem to a RelayCommand in the ViewModel, I tried all kinds of RelativeSource bindings, but nothing seems to work...

How should I configure the RelativeSource binding?

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem
        Header="Bla"
        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=DataContext.MyRelayCommand}" />
```

I get binding errors like

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource
>   FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TreeView',
>   AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.ExcludeSeasonCommand;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property
>   is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, after many many many google searches I ran into the solution

```
<MenuItem
    Header="Exclude season"
    Command="{Binding DataContext.MyRelayCommand, Source={x:Reference _myTreeView}}" />
```

Because the HierarchicalDataTemplate does not appear in the visual tree, there is not "relative" source...

I hope this helps somebody else who's pulling his/her hair out...

Comment: Would be vey helpful if you add in your answer where the _myTreeView reference is defined and how. Thanks!

Comment: @juagicre it's just the container of elements, you just set its name to _myTreeView and that's all

Answer (score 1):

Another commonly used solution:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work here, maybe has something to do with the context menu being placed on the TreeView childrens item?