# WPF Caliburn.Micro binding ViewModel property inside ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

How can I bind Visibility of TooTip to ToolTipVisibility property which is in ViewModel?
I have MenuObject class,

```
public class MenuObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IconPath { get; set; }
}
```

MenuObjects collection, ToolTipVisibility property in ViewModel,

```
public class MainViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    private bool _toolTipVisibility;
    private ObservableCollection<MenuObject> _menuItems;
    public bool ToolTipVisibility
    {
        get { return _toolTipVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _toolTipVisibility = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ToolTipVisibility);
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MenuObject> MenuItems
    {
        get { return _menuItems; }
        set
        {
            _menuItems = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MenuItems);
        }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ToolTipVisibility = true;
    }
    public void ToggleVisibility()
    {
        ToolTipVisibility = !ToolTipVisibility;
    }
}
```

and ListView binding with this collection

```
<ListView  x:Name="MenuItems">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2vc"/>
         </DataTemplate.Resources>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=IconPath}" Stretch="None" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="25,0,0,0"/>
            <StackPanel.ToolTip>
               <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                        Visibility="{Binding ..., Converter={StaticResource b2vc}}"/> <!--// How can i do this? //-->
            </StackPanel.ToolTip>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Help me, please. Thank you! :)

UPDATE:
I tried many ways and still can't resovle it. But I found out something. If I put this

```
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
    AncestorType={x:Type Window}, AncestorLevel=1},
    Path=DataContext.ToolTipVisibility, Converter={StaticResource b2vc}}"
```

in tag `StackPanel`, then it works fine. But if i put same thing in tag `ToolTip`, it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. Here is the asnwer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26223802/13230344
This is for my case:

```
 <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
          Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ToolTipVisibility,
          Source={x:Reference MenuItems}, Converter={StaticResource b2vc}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question. By visible I'm going to assume that you mean "visible when mouse over", since that is what `Visibility` does for the `ToolTip` property in WPF.

I used the following view model, which is quite similar to yours. I left out all other bindings than visibility, for simplicty:

```
private bool _isToolTipVisible;

// The 'ToolTip.Visibility' will be bound to this property
public bool IsToolTipVisible
{
    get => _isToolTipVisible;
    set
    {
        _isToolTipVisible = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(IsToolTipVisible));
    }
}

// This is just so that I am able to demonstrate the effect
public void ChangeToolTipVisibility()
{
    IsToolTipVisible = !IsToolTipVisible;
}
```

For the view, I did pretty much what you are already doing, just adding a binding to `IsToolTipVisible`, to control the visibilty of the tool tip. The button I added, is just to be able to demonstrate the effect (in calls the method `ChangeToolTipVisibility()`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2vc"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Margin="100">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Content="Lorem ipsum" Visibility="{Binding IsToolTipVisible, Converter={StaticResource b2vc}}"/>
        </StackPanel.ToolTip>

        <TextBlock Text="Button text" Margin="25,0,0,0"/>                
        <Button x:Name="ChangeToolTipVisibility" Content="Change visiblity" />

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

That's all it takes. So you were pretty much there already, assuming that I understood your question correctly :-)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it's not what i mean. My question is how to bind property inside ItemTemplate, which is not property of object. I mean I know how to bind "Name" and "IconPath", which are properties of "MenuObject", but i dont know how to bind "ToolTipVisibility" also in ItemTemplate. Hope you will understand, sorry xd

Comment: Frick, I missed that part. Sorry.

Comment: @loykods `Visibility="{TemplateBinding _someProperty_, ElementName=_otherControlName_}`"

Comment: @aepot I have an error: "Could not find property "ElementName" in type "TemplateBindingExtension". It works with "Binding" instead of "TemplateBinding", but what _otherControlName_ I need to write, if my "_someProperty_" is not property of any controls. "_someProperty_" is just a public property in my ViewModel

Comment: @loykods yes, sorry for misleading. My mistake. Try `{Binding _someProperty_, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=_parentControlType_}}` then, in case you need some parent Control's property.

Comment: @aepot I've updated question. Do you know what it could be?