# WPF binding inside a datatemplate but from another datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, datatemplate

So I have a `Treeview` which I bind an `ObservableCollection<T>` to. Inside the `Treeview` is a `HierarchicalDataTemplates` for that `DataType={x:Type T}` with a `ContextMenu`. the `ContextMenu` is either `Visible` or `Collapsed`, which is determined by the `bool` **UserCanDelete**. My goal is to have a `Datatrigger` refering to **UserCanDelete**, but it is not inside the same `Datatype` as the List.

XAML:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding List}">

 <TreeView.Resources>
   <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type T}">

     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35"> 
       ... 
       <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu>
           <MenuItem Header="Bla">
             <MenuItem.Style>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>

                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UserCanDelete, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataBlubb}}}" Value="False">
                   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                 </DataTrigger>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UserCanDelete, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataBlubb}}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                 </DataTrigger>

               </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
            </MenuItem.Style>
          </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
      </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
     </StackPanel>
   </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
 </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

DataContext:

```
public class DataBlubb
{
 public DataBlubb()
 {
   List = new ObservableCollection<T>();
   UserCanDelete = false;
 }

 public ObservableCollection<T> List {get;set;}
 public bool UserCanDelete { get;set;}
}
```

Is there a way to make this work without having the `bool` inside the list-elements?

Comment: There is no `DataBlubb` ancestor. Use `Binding="{Binding DataContext.UserCanDelete, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}"`. Not sure if it may also be necessary to set the Binding's Source instead of RelativeSource, e.g. as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26223802/1136211

Comment: Besides that, it isn't really clear where exactly the UserCanDelete property is, since there is no ItemsSource Binding in your XAML to `ObservableCollection<T> List`, only `TopLevelLocations` and `Items`.

Comment: Well your edit did the trick. I don't understand why this works, but it does... Thank you.

Comment: My mistake, I'll edit for future visitors.

Comment: @Clemens If you want to take credit write an answer which I can except. I can't upvote your comments.